# PHP and Javascript: EURO sign taking more character length in php than javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I got my message text as

> Available for order in Cologne of 05/16/2012 6:45 to 05/26/2012 ?
>   payment 10  €  Per day

I think Euro symbol  is villain

**When checking with the Euro sign:**

JavaScript char count= 86
PHP char count       = 88

**When checking without Euro sign**

JavaScript char count= 84
PHP char count       = 84

Why this is happening , anybody could explain ?

Comment: Can you show exact code? Are you using double quotes? If so, try single quotes.

Comment: Beware of utf8 encoding :) https://gist.github.com/2787184

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&euro;`.

Also, try outputting the string after running it through an escaping function.

Answer (score 0):

Available for order in Cologne of 05/16/2012 6:45 to 05/26/2012 ? payment 10 € Per day

replace `€` with `&euro;` you will get same result in both php and js

Answer (score 0):

It has most probably something to do with your internal encoding, see http://jsfiddle.net/e4phA/ where it alerts the string length correctly as 3 for the string '10€'.

Comment: I think there is no problem in js. The count problem is in php.

Comment: If the € sign is adding 2 to the length in JS, there is still some error. It's only a single character. But since it's a multi-byte symbol in UTF-8 it seems to be converted to ASCII or something for the length determination.

Comment: I tried it in the console and length is 1. :) `var s = "€";
console.log(s.length);